# Testing for creating Party Member Scenes continuously - Able to create multiple but after the first is custom type is not determined

Tags: gdscript, godot-4

For my quick test to see if I can create multiple combatants for my battles, I would like to be able to continuous create party members/enemies in order to get to the correct amount of combatants expected (the total amount).

The debugger is showing the root scene children to be:

```
Running Applications... Party Member<ID:Area2D> ... @Area2D@6#ID
```

where the expected output should be:

```
Running Applications... Party Member<ID:Area2D> ... Party Member<ID:Area2D>
```

and so on, including the enemy types as well

So it looks like it is reverting back to the Area2D, rather than staying as the Party Member class custom object.

I have followed many different ways of creating the new instances but none are working as expected.
I was able to test quite a lot up until now where I need to be able to access the object properly in order to determine what type it is and call the expected function, etc.

```
func createPartyMemberObject(root, job):
    
    partyPath = load("res://Resources/Party Members/Party Member.tscn")
    
    var party = partyPath.instantiate()
    party.resource = job

    print_debug(party)

    root.add_child(party)

    print_debug(party)

    return party
```

In fact it seems to keep the Party Member class up until it is ready to be added to the root path.
So it keeps the class name until after adding the child into the scene root (add_child). - I'm not sure if there is something that I am missing here.

For the first instance it continues as expected, but from the second instance on it isn't working properly.

I have tried creating multiple different variables in order to track the different party members but that didn't work either.

Possibly it has something to do with the partyPath, but I'm not sure what it could be.
maybe the instantiate only works for the one object rather than multiple. Commenting out the load var and keeping at a higher level, etc. didn't work.

I couldn't find any bugs in godot github, so I'm not sure if it is a bug or something that I am missing.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your `class_name` is "Party Member"? I'm not sure that's a valid `class_name`. Could you try "PartyMember" or "Party_Member"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is about the `name` of the `Node`s. That is an `String` that can change, so do not rely on it for checking the type. If you need the name to be something specific, set it. The issue is that Godot will keep the `name` of the `Node` if there is no collision, for the second instance there is already a `Node` with that `name`, so Godot generates a `name`... And it doesn't use the `class_name` or the original `name` to do it. The process has performance implications for games that make lots of `Node`s dynamically, so I'll reiterate that if you need the name, set it.

Answer (score 1):

Try statically typing your vars (and `func` return value), like this:

```
var party_scene := preload("res://Resources/Party Members/Party Member.tscn")

func createPartyMemberObject(root, job) -> PartyMember:
  var party: PartyMember = party_scene.instantiate()
  ...
```

[Source](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html).

Comment: Thanks. I did try this to figure out if there is some debugging options, due to the expected syntax. I feel a bit silly about leaving the return empty. In this case though it didn't help much to solve my problem. I am getting the same feedback - @Area2D@6, etc. Not sure if there is anything further to do with this response.

Comment: The return of the func it's just for you to know. Have you tried typing the `var party : PartyMember`?

Comment: yes. thanks. i did add the `var party: partymember`. I had copied your example as another test. I updated my Party Member.gd to have a `class_name PartyMember` based on the other comment :)

Comment: I still wasn't able to figure out why the objects were named as they were after the second object was created. But through the static typed format I have worked out how to properly compare objects. It seems that even if the names aren't correct the object is still a `PartyMember` Class and so can be used as I had originally expected. I have then updated my code to reflect this class comparison rather than the name of the object itself. ... `if i is PartyMember`, etc.